# Is the URL part of metadata?

Tags: metadata

I am using SharePoint 2013. My question is about metadata.

When I name a library, document or task list's URL, is that URL part of the metadata?

In addition, is that the reason to use underscores or Camel-Case? In other words the %20 in the URL name will hinder the efficiency of the metadata?

Thank you for your h elp.

Answer (score 1):

It can be if organized properly. Consider what we can gleen from a url like:

`https://tenant.sharepointonline.com/teams/finance/capex`

Now looking at this, we can see that this is probably a finance site, with either a document library or subsite related to capital expenditures.

It isn't as apparent what this is:

`https://tenant.sharepointonline.com/teams/finance/documents`